# Draw a line through a circle

Tags: css

I'm getting trouble with drawing a line through a circle.

I'd like to have a line that also adapt to the div height, this is what I tried so far :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__level opacity-10">
        <div class="item__level__round"></div>
        <div class="item__level__line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS

```
.item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
    .item__level{
      width: 10%;
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;

    }

    .item__level__round{
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: #1F8AEE;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);      
    }

    .item__level__line{
      position: absolute;
      border-left: 2px solid red;
      left: 12%;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%; 
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQMdjm

It seems like the red line is not perfectly in the center of the circle, is it an optic illusion ? I'm on this since a while

[image: This is what I try to reproduce]

Comment: *"It seems like the red line is not perfectly in the center of the circle, is it an optic illusion ? I'm on this since a while"* - It would take less than a minute to verify this by counting pixels in your screenshot (using Paint or so).

Comment: Just did that. Looks like in the posted screenshot, the circle is dead center.

Comment: like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp)? you could always use  the pseudo element :after.

Comment: Perfect thanks, thats exactly what I looked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update** - Sorry, I just reread your question. Yea the line could be off by a pixel depending on the widths. Check this fiddle for an example https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/pzo4fe2a/ (red line is 20px wide and blue line is 21px. It doesn't cut a pixel in half so the full 1px difference appears to the right (in FF) instead of a half pixel on left and the second half on right. If you're doing percentage widths and heights the issue can occur in responsive design because you can't control the device width.

original answer - Try adding left: 50% and top 50% to your circle and line and use the -50% to compensate and keep it centered.

```css
.container {
  display: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Play with the fiddle pane to see it respond to viewscreen size.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/7d8ebqxm/